# Why do I need to "fuse" both objects to use "display: flex;" CSS?

Tags: css, flexbox

In this code both box will appear in line together (horizontal)

```
<style>
  #box{
    display: flex;
    height: 500px;

  }
#box-1 {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
  }

#box-2 {
    background-color: red;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
  }
</style>

<div id="box">
  <div id="box-1"></div>
  <div id="box-2"></div>
</div>
```

Why when i don't arrange them under "box" they displayed as 2 separated elements, one under the other? Why it's not displayed the same as in the code above even though I used the `display: flex;` in both of the box style. As I understood (from reading online), this function was needed to make them both appear as in the code above

```
#box-1 {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    display: flex;
  }

#box-2 {
    background-color: orangered;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    display: flex;
  }
</style>

<div id="box-1"></div>
<div id="box-2"></div>
```

I expected that the second code should give the same as the first one.
I understood that probably I'm wrong (from the results), but I can't understand why.

Thank you!

Comment: Flex is some funstuff indeed ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why when i don't arrange them under "box" they displayed as 2 separated elements

That's because `div` elements by default has `display:block` which means it takes it own line from left to right, that's why they stack one under the other

However `display:flex` makes an element a `block level flex container` same as `block` only it affect the children too, the children become `flex items`, where you can control using the flex properties [<sup>ref</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox), and by default it has the property `flex-direction` set to `row` means the `flex items` will display horizontally, as a row

## Demo

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  width:100px;
}

.box-1 {
  background-color: blue;
  flex: 1;
}

.box-2 {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 1
}

.row {
  flex-direction: row;
}

.column {
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<h2>flex-direction: row</h2>
<div class="box row">
  <div class="box-1"></div>
  <div class="box-2"></div>
</div>


<h2>flex-direction: column</h2>
<div class="box column">
  <div class="box-1"></div>
  <div class="box-2"></div>
</div>
```

Might wanna consider using `flex` property rather than `width`

Answer (score 0):

What makes your 'box1 and box2 appear in one line is the `display: flex` setting in their *parent* element - the `#box` element! That makes its children elements "flex items" - the children don't need *any* setting to become flex items (you can erase the flex stuff from the rules for the child elements), that's all due to the setting in the parent element.